# Use of 差し込む to describe the sun

Tags: grammar, words

I have this sentence:

> **建物と建物の間から差し込む**太陽が音もなく世界を赤くにじませる夕方、...
>
> An evening in which the sun **piercing from between buildings** silently blurs the world with red.

I'm struggling with what the sun is actually doing, and with the geometry of the scene.

Is the verb 差し込む normally used to talk about the sun shining or is this just fancy poetic writing? Is it shining or thrusting or piercing etc?

As for the geometry, it's clear that something is happening **between buildings** but I'm not sure what. From the use of から I have a picture of the sun on one side of the buildings shining through a gap. It is the sunlight **from/から** this gap that is "silently blurring the world in red". Do I have the correct kind of image? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the translation is quite appropriate, but it makes sense to me.

Then granted,

> Is the verb 差し込む normally used to talk about the sun shining or is this just fancy poetic writing? Is it shining or thrusting or piercing etc?

It goes without saying **the sun itself** can not **come through** the narrow gap between the buildings.

So, here sure, it means the **sun light** ( so that I guess the writer used the word "pierce" in order to express the **sun light**, **not directly but indirectly**? )

FYI From **[大辞林](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B7%AE%E3%81%97%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%E3%83%BB%E5%B7%AE%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%E3%83%BB%E5%B0%84%E3%81%97%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80-274642#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)**

> 差し込む・差込む・射し込む

差し込む is dealt same with **射し**込む. The verb 射す reminds me of piercing or penetrating, by arrows personally, so may be the writer used the word **pierce** because everybody knows sun itself can not come to you directly.....

From the very source

> （「射し込む」とも書く）光が入ってくる。 「窓から朝日が－・む」

Translated

> ( as is written as 射し込む ) meaning, the sun **light** comes. Ex : 「 The morning sun light has begun to be seen at the window. 」

Have a happy day.

Comment: FYI から is as you say, is here used as **from**, because it falls into the translation method, I think you might better take it as "through" than "from" because in English sense the **sun light** does not come **from** somewhere.........